Есть ли слово «барахтать»?
Существует ли слово "барахтать"?
Предложение: Ребенок барахтал ногами.

Я бы написал: ребёнок барашил воду ногами. Или "ребёнок дрыгал ногами в воде".

Ребенок барахтал ногами – это условная запись, но никак не предложение.  Значение слова проявляется в реальном тексте, например:  Ребенок только смеялся и весело барахтал ножками.  Как записать? Дрыгал, колотил  – все некрасиво, не то.

Любопытно и то, когда слово получило единственную возвратную норму?  Все примеры из литературы с барахтать очень убедительны, замены там нет.  В двух случаях есть Т.п. Так что стремление к однообразию не всегда полезно.

Такого слова нет - даже в диалектах.
Есть "барахтаться", но этот глагол непереходный.

спасибо большое

• В обычных словарях этого глагола нет.
Есть барахтаться — делать быстрые беспорядочные движения телом, руками, ногами, стараясь подняться, освободиться от чего-либо или выплыть.
• Нашелся же он в словаре русских народных говоров вот с какими значениями (стр. 109):
барáхтать, -аю, -аешь,  несов., перех.
1. Осиливать, одолевать кого-либо. Шадр. Перм., 1859. Сев., Петрозав. Олон.
2. Бросать, толкать (куда-нибудь). Прямо его барахтай в жар. Липец. Тамб., 1863.
• Имеются примеры использования в Нацкорпусе (см.).
Одновременно она мыла люстру, барахтая резные стекляшки в тазу с мыльным раствором, где сформировалась великолепная голубоватая пена (Василий Нагибин. Пена // «Волга», 2013).
Зинаида Николаевна развязала ленточки кружевного конвертика. Маленькое розовое существо барахтало ножками (Анатолий Мариенгоф. Роман без вранья (1927)).
Гичка летела мимо прогулочных лодок, где люди в подтяжках беспомощно барахтали веслами (А. Н. Толстой. Гиперболоид инженера Гарина (1925-1927|1937)).
Освирепев, терзали и барахтали собаки страшного зверя, а он, не обороняясь, только рычал, сначала умоляюще, потом сурово и злобно (Б. А. Садовской. Лебединые клики (1911)).
● Так что слово такое есть, но говорить "барахтать ногами" неверно (а пример столетней давности — не в счет).

спасибо, шикарная информация!

На здоровье, Наталья! Вы ведь хотели узнать, есть ли слово «барахтать». Есть. А ваш выбор принятого ответа быстр и, право, странен. Чего же ж такого нового или интересного вы оттуда почерпнули? Мне кажется, не надо торопиться.

Дополнение к ответам
ДИАЛОГ
Одновременно она мыла люстру, барахтая резные стекляшки в тазу с мыльным раствором, где сформировалась великолепная голубоватая пена (Василий Нагибин. Пена // «Волга», 2013).
 —  Так нельзя писать! В словаре нет такого слова!
 —  А почему его там нет?

В русском языке слово известно с первой половины XVII века: "Родька с Потапкой барахталис, а за что он того не ведает"(1639 год). До этого слово фиксировалось в говорах, в том числе с невозвратным значением.
У Даля: Сбарахтал с плеч, свалил.
Здесь "барахтались" — боролись, отсюда возвратность. Глагол этимологически неясный, а по смыслу в нем совмещены значения "бороться с чем-либо или кем-либо" и "делать беспорядочные движения", что хорошо видно по современным примерам в Карте слов.
А если нам нужно только  значение беспорядочного движения, то как быть? Как записать: "барахтал резные стекляшки в тазу"?
У слов разные судьбы: они появляются, меняют свое значение, устаревают и появляются вновь. И когда слово возвращается в язык с другим семантическим оттенком, то надо приглядеться к нему, а не гнать сразу прочь. А вдруг это нужное для нас слово?
